# Can't get Fullcalendar to display in cordova application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, fullcalendar

I am developing a mobile application using ionic and cordova, I am trying to implement a timetable system using Fullcalendar and a PHP page that displays MySQL in JSON format. I am having an issue getting the Fullcalendar to display on the page. I am using the Angular UI Router that comes packaged in cordova.

Here's the Header where the scripts are referenced:

```
    <!--Fullcalendar libs-->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='../plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css'/>
    <script src='../plugins/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='../plugins/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='../plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
```

And in app.js where I place the "$(document).ready(function()" script:

```
var App = angular.module("App", ["ionic"]);

$(document).ready(function() {

// page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // put your options and callbacks here
})

});
```

I have looked at the console in chrome and I am not getting any irregular errors. Is there something else I should be doing? I am open to alternative methods and ideas about how to go about this as implementing this system has been a severe time sync in the project overall. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*UPDATE:* I have attempted to install the Angular-UI/UI-Calander that was linked in the comments by X31. However upon attempting to implement the library, I ran into a large amount of errors referring to something not being defined. After retracing my steps and undoing all of the ui-calendar installation, I have started again and managed to get Bower to work, however I have been presented with 3 options of installing jquery.

*Update 2*: I have managed to work the errors down to one "Type Error: undefined is not a function" This makes me think hat X31 was right and I am missing a lib. Here is what I am calling in the header of my html (note: I have commented out the angular.js call because I am already calling that somewhere else and it was throwing a warning.):

```
    <!--Fullcalendar libs-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/fullcalendar/gcal.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid jquery plugins in Angular as it will work outside the angular scope and digest (not recommended for angular apps). You can try angular directives [Angular Version of FullCalendar](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar)

To add a calendar you can do something like this then

```
<div ui-calendar ng-model="eventSources"></div>
```

Comment: Im reading through this guide on how to run it, and the file "components.json" is not in my project. The closest thing I have is "bower.json" is that what I should be looking for?

Comment: Yeah that is your component file

Comment: ower EMALFORMED    Failed to read /Users/unsername/newTestApp/bower.json

Additional error details:
Unexpected string.     I keep getting this error

Comment: Get the cdn path or download directly from github

Comment: i managed to implement it following the instructions provided, but now I am getting 8 errors; 7 of which are "length is undefined" and 1 saying "undefined is not a function" no doubt referring to length.

Comment: You must have not inclided one library for sure. Can you update your question